# RSpec --only-failures wrong output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

When I run RSpec it gives the following output:

```
$ rspec
.F

Failures:

1) A cup of coffee with milk costs $1.25
   Failure/Error: expect(coffee.price).to eq(1.25)

   expected: 1.25
        got: 1.0

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/coffee_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 0.02668 seconds (files took 0.12828 seconds to load)
 2 examples, 1 failure

 Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/coffee_spec.rb:11 # A cup of coffee with milk costs $1.25
```

So when I run

```
$ rspec --only-failures
```

The output should be

```
Run options: include {:last_run_status=>"failed"}
F
« truncated »
1 example, 1 failure
Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/coffee_spec.rb:11 # A cup of coffee with milk costs $1.25
```

But instead of that I get this:

```
Run options: include {:last_run_status=>"failed"}

All examples were filtered out


Finished in 0.00158 seconds (files took 0.13118 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures
```

I already added this to the spec file 
`RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.example_status_persistence_file_path = "examples.txt"
end`

This is the output from the examples.txt:
[examples.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyFUs.png)

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `examples.txt`?

Comment: @ndn Added an image link

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the problem?

```
config.example_status_persistence_file_path = 'spec/examples.txt'

Cannot find 'example_status_persistence_file_path='
```

Comment: Yea, that would be a problem. When do you get this error? And if you do, how was the `examples.txt` file generated to begin with.

Comment: @ndn I get this error in the coffee_spec.rb file. The file was created automatically after I ran it the first time.

Comment: Do you still get it if you inline the rspec configuration in the spec file (for experimentation's sake)?

Comment: @ndn I am not sure what you mean, could you be more specific please :) ?

Comment: Take the `RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.example_status_persistence_file_path = "examples.txt"
end` stuff and put it in the spec file you are running.

Comment: I already have that `RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"
end`

Comment: It's very strange that this will run normally on the first run and fail when you apply the filter. Is this the exact error being printed?

Comment: @ndn Yes I use Ruby Mine and that is the error it shows when I hover over it with my mouse. In the documentation of RSpec it says: "RSpec re-runs the formerly failing example and verifies that it passes. If we
try this process once more, RSpec won’t have any failing examples left to run." But even the first time it didn't run right, I also tried it with a new .txt file but same problem.

Comment: Could you run it in from the console instead and share that? It does seem that for whatever reason it doesn't pick the configuration in some cases. That is why I asked to inline it and run for a specific file.

Comment: So I ran it in the /spec directory, not sure if that is the right way but anyway this is the outcome in the cmd: `RSpec.configure do |config|
> c.example_status_persistence_file_path = "examples.txt"
bash: RSpec.configure: command not found
bash: config: command not found
bash: c.example_status_persistence_file_path: command not found`

Comment: Lets say you have a spec called `cats_spec.rb`. Put the `RSpec.configure do |config| config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt" end` spiel at the top of that spec and run in the console: `bundle exec rspec cats_spec.rb`.

Comment: Not sure what I did but it worked! I deleted the examples.txt file and created a new one and now it works. I have no idea what the problem was because it stil says `Cannot find 'example_status_persistence_file_path='`. Thanks anyway for the help :)

Comment: @EgonMeijers, could you paste the full contents of `coffee_spec.rb` here, or to https://gist.github.com?

Comment: @EgonMeijers, it looks like you found the solution; glad it's working now. Thanks for adding the code. I can confirm that it works with Ruby 2.4 and RSpec 3.6: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8348d53d44011de04da64cca775be3e9

Comment: @undees thanks for trying yourself, I use both Ruby 2.4 and RSpec 3.6 as well :)

Answer (score 0):

**Code coffee_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = 'spec/examples.txt'
end

RSpec.describe 'A cup of coffee' do
  let (:coffee) { Coffee.new }

  it 'costs $1' do
    expect(coffee.price).to eq(1.00)
  end

  context 'with milk' do
    before { coffee.add :milk }

    it 'costs $1.25' do
      expect(coffee.price).to eq(1.25)
    end
  end
end

class Coffee
  def ingredients
    @ingredients ||= []
  end

  def add(ingredient)
    ingredients << ingredient
  end

  def price
    1.00
  end

end
```